# Secret construction

Tags: algorithm-design

Given set of random strings $w =\{s_1, s_2, s_3 ... s_n\}$ are there any algorithms to construct single master secret $S$ from them? Subsequently we should be able to deconstruct the $S$ back to initial set of strings $w$.

This is opposite of traditional secret sharing algorithms where given $S$ could be shared into secrets.

Edit : The string $S$ should be smaller in length than all the lengths of $s_i$ combined.

Edit 2 : Should be able to extract selected strings in $w$ from $S$ without reconstructing the entire set

Comment: Do you have particular security properties in mind? ​ ​

Comment: I have added one condition to be able to reconstruct the original set back. am looking for any basic algorithm, additional properties like reconstructing from subset etc. would be a bonus for me !

Comment: I believe just concatinating the random strings (with delimiters) would satisfy all the security requirements you have listed.

Comment: Oops yes. let me edit the question , i forgot an important property

Comment: In other words, you're looking for a compression function that'll work for random input???

Comment: added another edit 2 , sorry should have been more clear upfront

Comment: edited answer ​ ​

Comment: By an entropy argument, the added requirement _"The string $S$ should be smaller in length than all the lengths of $s_i$ combined"_, together with the initial requirement _"we should be able to deconstruct the $S$ back to initial set of $w =\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\}$"_, implies that at least one of the $s_i$ has entropy lower than its length in bit, or the $s_i$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.
$\langle\{s_1,s_2,s_3,...,s_n\},\{\text{selected}_{\hspace{.03 in}1},\text{selected}_{\hspace{.04 in}2},\text{selected}_{\hspace{.03 in}3},...,\text{selected}_{\hspace{.04 in}m}\hspace{-0.03 in}\}\rangle \; \mapsto$

[prefixfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}s_{\text{selected}_1}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)$ [||](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) prefixfree$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}s_{\text{selected}_2}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)$ ||

prefixfree$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}s_{\text{selected}_3}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)$ || ... || prefixfree$\left(\hspace{-0.02 in}s_{\text{selected}_m}\hspace{-0.03 in}\right)$

, with an efficiently-invertible prefix-free code.